# React router 4 server-side rendering using IIS, not express

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux, server-side-rendering, react-router-v4

I'm trying to do server-side rendering using react-router v4. All the documentation out there is using express server, but I am using windows iis. I can get it to work on client only rendering but when i try to render server-side i get the error "hash history needs a dom". Any suggestions?

I'm sure everything is being imported properly so I'm deleting the imports out of the below code.

Here is the code:

```js
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);


const someText = <p><strong>Some JSX component</strong><br/>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
const simpleContent = (props) => { console.log(props); return (<SimpleContent placeholders={{leftColumn: <Counter data={{title: 'Nested counter'}}/>, rightColumn: <Timer data={{title: 'Nested counter'}}/>}}/>) }

const RouteHub = (props) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
           <HashRouter>
            <div>
              <h1>Title</h1>
                <ul>
                  <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/simple">Simple Content</Link></li>
                </ul>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact name="index" path='/' component={simpleContent}/>
                <Route name="simple" path='/simple' component={SimpleContent}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </HashRouter>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default RouteHub;
```

Comment: You should use `StaticRouter` instead of HashRouter on server. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/StaticRouter

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was resolved by using StaticRouter instead of the HashRouter.

Thanks egig!